# how to combine these two queries in a single query

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to combine these two queries into single query

**1.** `select sum(amount) as received from voucher where amount>0`

**2.** `select sum(amount) as repaid from voucher where amount<0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use conditional aggregation

```
select sum( case when amount > 0 then amount else 0 end ) as received,
       sum( case when amount < 0 then amount else 0 end ) as repaid 
FROM t
```

You may use `FILTER` in Postgres 9.4 +

```
select sum( amount ) filter (where  amount > 0 ) as received,
       sum( amount ) filter (where  amount < 0 ) as repaid 
FROM t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.,

```
select case when amount>0 then sum(amount) end as 'received', 
case when amount<0 then sum(amount) end as 'repaid' from voucher
```